# Parsing a large text file Python vs c#

Tags: c#, python, regex, parsing

What is the fastest way of parsing a 8GB text file? Will Pythons performance be comparable to c#?

```
exampledomain NS ns.anameserver.com.
exampledomain NS ns2.anameserver.com.
exampledomain NS ns3.anameserver.com.
anotherdomain NS ns1.nameservers.com.
cooldomain NS ns.example.com.
cooldomain NS ns2.example.com.
```

I need to parse each line and update a database table with first and third item for each line, ignoring the NS in each line.

Comment: You really need to expand further on what you're attempting to do, how fast you can parse it is entirely dependent on the actual process, not to mention latency in updating the database as well as variable read speeds on different storage mediums.

Comment: well, parsing a text file is quite easy... therefore, parse it and compare the results

Comment: If it is critical that you know which Regex engine is faster then you should try both.

Comment: In virtually all cases the IO for reading the input file will be more involved than the processing you do (unless that processing itself involves IO, in which case the string manipulation portion of the processing will still be a tiny portion of the program).  I'm willing to bet that it just won't matter.  The only think you may need to worry about is ensuring you stream the data and don't bring the whole file in to memory at once.

Answer (score 4):

The parsing performance will almost certainly be completely irrelevant here. I'd expect the contributions to be something like:

- Database access for writing the data
- Disk access for reading the data
- CPU for parsing

in that order, with quite possibly an order of magnitude difference between each bullet, depending on whether the database is local or not (and the speed of the network etc) and the disk type (if it's an SSD that will be a lot faster).

I'd expect both Python and C# to be fine for this, assuming they both have reasonably efficient database drivers for whichever database you're talking to - use whichever language you will find easier to maintain.

Note that while you could certainly take advantage of *some* parallelism, if the network ends up being the bottleneck it may well not make very much difference. Batching the database writes may well be more important - that's the bit you should experiment with, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

something like this would work:

```
ins = open( "file.txt", "r" )
for line in ins:
    linesplit = line.split(" ")
    # linesplit should contain your 3 elements which you can then insert into your db
```

- If you need to trim the line first, you can do that using trim

The performance limitation will most likely be your database write/insert speed.

If you're using mysql, you can use "insert delayed" to speed up the inserting process as this will dispatch the query and return right away.

You can also disable indexes while doing your inserts (if primary/unique is not needed) and this should speed up db insert performance also.

If you're doing updates, make sure your lookup columns are indexed.

in c# it would be something like this

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt");
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
             string[] linesplit = line.Split(' ');
             // linesplit has your elements, do your db stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I imagine the performance to be virtually identical between the two languages with a memory footprint overhead advantage to c#.  You should try both and report back.

Comment: the c# example would load the whole file into memory `while ((line = streamreader.ReadLine()) != null)` would be much more efficient

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with c#, but I'll update my answer as reading the entire file into memory is hardly ideal for resource usage, and processing the file as it's being read is almost always faster.